# When can we make two numbers zero after repeatedly subtracting some number to one, and its double to the other?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

I encountered the below problem in a contest and got the solution from its editorial. But I still can't figure out how the solution works. Can somebody help me prove that the conditions in the solution are correct?

#### Problem

Given two positive integers, $a$ and $b$, with $a<b$, find if it's possible to make $a$ and $b$ simultaneously zero after performing any number of the below operations:

- Choose any positive integer $$ and set $a\to a-x$, $b\to b-2x$ 
  **OR**  $a\to a-2x$ $b\to b-x$. *(For each operation, you can choose different value of $\mathit x$)*.

#### Solution

It's possible to make $a$ and $b$ equal to $0$ simultaneously if they satisfy the two conditions below:

- $(a+b)\equiv0\pmod3$
- $2a\geq b$

#### How can we prove that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can clearly combine all of the operations in which we take an amount from $a$, and its double from $b$, into a single operation. Likewise, we can combine all operations in which we take an amount from $b$, and its double from $a$. This means that the pairs we can reach from a starting pair $(a,b)$ are exactly the pairs of the form $$(a-x-2y,b-2x-y).$$ That is, we can reach $(0,0)$ iff the system $$\left\{\begin{array}{c}a=x+2y\\b=2x+y\end{array}\right.$$ has non-negative, integral solutions for $x$, $y$. However, we can easily solve this system as $$\left\{\begin{array}{c}x=\frac{2a-b}3\\y=\frac{2b-a}3\end{array}\right.$$ $x$, $y$ will be non-negative integers iff $3\mid 2a-b$, $3\mid 2b-a$, $2a\geq b$, $2b\geq a$. Since $a<b$, and by elementary modular arithmetic, this set of conditions is equivalent to the desired one. $\blacksquare$

Comment: +1 better answer than mine :)

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit No need to delete it! Extra insight is never frowned upon.

Comment: Thanks @URL for such a nice answer. Got it))